# How to resolve the path to a jar in the dependency tree

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a maven project which is running fine on my machine but not on another machine. Apparently in the other machine, mvn in unable to resolve the path to the jar, resulting in a `ClassNotFoundException`.
The missing class is part of a jar which is an indirect dependency (i.e. dependency of a dependency) and is not directly referred in my pom. Is there any way to determine the path to the jar in my dependency tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` : it will print a tree with all the dependencies. Once done, search the tree for the missing jar to see where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's POM editor has a useful dependency hierarchy view. Another way to test these things is to delete bits of your `.m2/repository` directory (after backing it up) and seeing if it then also fails to build on your own machine.